# Java 8 turn on parallel() stream with boolean?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I am wondering how I could design methods that could either be run concurrently or single threaded. For example I have a method like this:

```
/**
 * Produces the norm of the two vector {@code v1}.
 * 
 * @param v1
 *            The first vector.
 * 
 * @param v2
 *            The second vector
 * 
 * @throws MathException
 *             Of type {@code DIMENSION_MISMATCH} if
 *             {@code v1.getDimension()} is != {@code v2.getDimension()}.
 */
public static Function<Vector, Double> norm = (v) -> {
    return Math.sqrt(
            IntStream.range(0, v.getDimension()).mapToDouble(i -> Math.pow(v.getEntry(i), 2)).sum());
};
```

And if I want to make the embedded stream parallel then I could create the same method over again and add `parallel()` to the stream but that adds a lot of boilerplate.  Is there a `parallel(boolean)` switch that can be used?

Comment: this is still asking for discussion and recommendations, the word **best** just highlights that, taking it out does not change the fundamental question which is still **opinion based**, and **too broad** at the same time. Taking out the word **best** just obfuscated these issues now.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Out of curiosity, how many different implementations of that can you think of?

Comment: if there is more than 1 way then there is going to be differing opinions on them, and there is the opinion that you do not need a function for this either. I am sure someone will have a `Spring` based solution at some point!

Comment: Of course in programming there is often different ways to solve a problem. That does not necessarily make a question opinion based or too broad...

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Not necessarily. Opinions comes into play when there are 2 same solutions just written differently. If not, there are non-opiniated way to compare them like performance. Will you honestly write a Spring solution here? Because you could write a Spring solution for every question possible. And no, there is no opinion on whether you want that: the OP wants it.

Comment: (If you're considering `parallel()` for performance, you may find `unordered()` gives a performance boost as well.)

Comment: @DavidConrad, unlikely taking into account current Stream API implementation. I benchmarked similar problem: seems that for such scenario `unordered()` does not add any benefit.

Comment: @Tagir You may be right, but I've seen some cases where it helped, and often the user doesn't care about ordering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no switch like this in the API itself but you can add it yourself quite easily:

```
public static Function<Vector, Double> getNorm(boolean parallel) {
    return v -> {
        IntStream stream = IntStream.range(0, v.getDimension());
        stream = parallel ? stream.parallel() : stream;
        return Math.sqrt(stream.mapToDouble(i -> Math.pow(v.getEntry(i), 2)).sum());
    };
};
```

This code simply calls [`parallel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#parallel--) or not depending on the boolean parameter.

Comment: A `BiFunction<Vector, Boolean, Double>` could also fit in there (although it uses the wrapper type but well...).

Comment: I don’t think that the conditional operator adds to readability here. An ordinary `if(parallel) stream=stream.parallel();` does the job straight-forward.

Comment: I agree with @Holger But still, very concise and beautiful solution!

Comment: Thanks you guys!  That's really sweet!  I'm considering adding the parallel feature for a Matrix / Vector module in order to experiment with concurrency in algorithms.  Do you think it makes sense to bake it in at the function level or should I target larger blocks of code for that?

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to post an example of what I think the API should look like in general to see what you think (I'm hoping Apache Commons Math will adopt this for 4.0, but the module will be available here meanwhile [firefly-math-linear-real](https://github.com/firefly-math/firefly-math-linear-real/)):

```
/**
 * Returns a {@link BiFunction} that multiplies the first vector {@code v1}
 * times the second vector {@code v2} .
 * 
 * Example {@code multiply().apply(v1, v2);}
 * 
 * @throws MathException
 *             Of type {@code DIMENSION_MISMATCH} if
 *             {@code v1.getDimension()} is != {@code v2.getDimension()}.
 */
public static BiFunction<Vector, Vector, Vector> multiply() {
    return VectorFunctions.multiply(false);
};

/**
 * Returns a {@link BiFunction} that multiplies the first vector {@code v1}
 * times the second vector {@code v2} .
 * 
 * Example {@code multiply(true).apply(v1, v2);}
 * 
 * @param parallel
 *            Whether to perform the multiplication in parallel.
 * 
 * @throws MathException
 *             Of type {@code DIMENSION_MISMATCH} if
 *             {@code v1.getDimension()} is != {@code v2.getDimension()}.
 */
public static BiFunction<Vector, Vector, Vector> multiply(boolean parallel) {
    return (v1, v2) -> {
        checkDimensionMismatch(v1, v2);
        IntStream stream = range(0, v1.getDimension());
        stream = parallel ? stream.parallel() : stream;
        return new Vector(stream.mapToDouble(i -> v1.getEntry(i)
                * v2.getEntry(i)).toArray());
    };
}
```

Thoughts?

Ole

Answer (score 0):

### Create two functions

one named *norm* (implementation as provided in question), another named *parallelNorm*. You could reuse code between those functions.

### Let encosing class controll parallelism

Your function *norm* resides in some class. I would

- make function *norm* non-static
- introduced final boolean member variable named *parallel* in encosing class
- initialize  *parallel* member variable in constructor
- function *norm* would use parallel or non-parallel streams, based on value of *parallel* member variable

### Use Decorator pattern to add parallelism

like in example above, I would use non-static function.
I would make one class named *Norm* (with implementation of *norm* function like above).
Then I would make class *ParallelNorm extends Norm* that would *@Override* *norm* function with parallel implementation

Comment: Thanks - I like your thinking as well.  think I'll probably do norm() that just returns the non parallel version and norm(boolean) that has the option to turn the parallel version on.